# OSX record already exists 2008 function level change

Tags: active-directory, mac-osx, mac-osx-server

This may be related to a server 2008 functional level change we recently underwent.  After that change, we started having problems with Macs binding to AD.  They'd just give us an error similar to what's in the title above and not allow us to add them.  We were able to fix it and I'm going to reply with the fix.

Answer (score 0):

To fix this, we simply added a computer account to Active Directory with the exact same name hostname as the computer we're trying to add (minus any domain/suffixes etc).  So if it is computer.localhost.local, we'd just add "computer" as an account to AD.  I don't know if this is necessary, but we've been setting it to "assign this computer account as a pre-Windows 2000" computer.

So in AD, you right-click on the top-level domain (or wherever you want your computer object to be) then choose new->computer

Type computer name.  Check the box for the setting above, click "ok" then try to rebind the OSX machine.